# How to cut short a long 'if' statement with multiple logical AND in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am parsing a logfile after doing 'ls' to see whether my build clean is complete:

```
if "ls: cannot access fepu/*.elf: No such file or directory" and "ls: cannot
access mpu/*.elf: No such file or directory" and "ls: cannot access  
sbmu/*.elf: No such file or directory" and "ls: cannot access fepu/*.elf: No  
such file or directory" in open(logfilePath).read():
```

The 'if' statement above looks clumsy and too huge. Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Are you looking for every "cannot access" or not?

Comment: What does this mean? You need to have each and every line of these in your log?

Comment: I need to check that after the "Build Clean" command whether all the elfs are eliminated from the respective folders (fepu, mpu etc.) So, after build clean, I am doing 'ls' of the corresponding folders and checking whether the elfs are absent

Comment: @user3565150, you can write such script without ```ls```. Look for ```glob``` and ```os``` modules.

Comment: @Jimilian, I am running the build clean command on a remote unix server after opening a paramiko transport session : session.exec_command('cd /project//neptune_psv/fw; ./Build.sh clean)

Comment: @Jimilian, I need to check whether I can use glob and os modules through this session

Comment: @user3565150, in this situation your design is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'm afraid your boolean expression is invalid as Jimilian points out.

Secondly, it's not a good idea to just `open()` and `.read()` a file, without closing it; CPython very likely auto-closes the open file handle but PyPy, Jython, IronPyton and other implementations might not, so instead use a `with` block to ensure the file handle gets closed (almost) no matter what happens:

```
with open(logfilePath) as f:
    contents = f.read()  # warning: bad with big files; see below
    ...
```

second, better to store the string literals in a variable:

```
needles = [
    "ls: cannot access fepu/*.elf: No such file or directory",
    "ls: cannot access mpu/*.elf: No such file or directory",
    "ls: cannot access sbmu/*.elf: No such file or directory",
]
```

(you had the `fepu` one twice so I removed it)

your code then becomes:

```
with open(logfilePath) as f:
    contents = f.read()
    if any(needle in contents for needle in needle):
        ...
```

---

Also, I would recommend against trying to refactor out the small-scale duplication in `needles` however, if `needles` grows to be bigger than 4 items, or the items should be computed dynamically, you might want to do smething like this:

```
folders = ['fepu', 'mpu', 'sbmu']

def mk_needle(folder_name):
    return "ls: cannot access %s/*.elf: No such file or directory" % folder_name

with open(logfilePath) as f:
    contents = f.read()
    if any(mk_needle(fname) in contents for fname in folders):
        ...
```

---

if your file is big, you might not want to use `.read()` and instead grab the lines iterator of the file, and do a nested `any`:

```
with open(logfilePath) as f:
    lines = f.xreadlines()  # or just readlines in Py 3

    def has_needle(line):
        return any(needle in line for needle in needles)

    if any(has_needle(line) for line in lines):
        ...
```

---

*P.S. I used the "needle in haystack" analogy, feel free to use the term "error" instead of "needle" in this particular case.*

Comment: Thank you, it gave me a lot of insight in handling such parsing and strings

Answer (score 2):

Your code is incorrect. Let me explain.
First of all, we extract variable for each line:

```
error1 = "ls: cannot access fepu/*.elf: No such file or directory"
error2 = "ls: cannot access mpu/*.elf: No such file or directory"
error3 = "ls: cannot access sbmu/*.elf: No such file or directory"
error4 = "ls: cannot access fepu/*.elf: No such file or directory"
```

Now your code looks like:

```
if error1 and error2 and error3 and error4 in open(logfilePath).read():
```

So, error1, error2 and error3 are `True` always. Because `string` is `False` only when it's `""` (empty) or `None`. And you are checking only last string.

Also, we can extract variable for file data:

```
data = open(logfilePath).read()
```

Now, it's obviously can be rewritten as:

```
if any(error in data for error in [error1, error2, error3, error4]):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the strings into a list, and then:

```
all(itm in open(logfilePath).read() for itm in lst)
```

Another option is to use regex, since all of your strings have a common pattern:

```
ls: cannot access <XXX>: No such file or directory
```

if you don't care about `<XXX>` you can replace it with a regex that matches all strings.